# how to perform joins with specific rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have two tables as below

```
users_table
id name customerId
1   a   0
2   b   0
3   c   1
```

```
customers_table
id name address
1   d   efg
```

i can perform normal joins as in mysql like users_table join customers_table.

as i have as many as customerId 0 in users_table so it will be costly to join for all with even customerId 0 when there is millions of data rows.
so my concern is why not to join customers_table only when customerId exists in users_table.

something like this

users_table rows joins customers_table rows if users_table customerId has value in it.

thanks!!

Comment: Shall I provide you a raw query for this?

Comment: yea sure. thats too going to help me out :)

Comment: May I know if you have considered right join? Starting from the customers_table and right joining it with users_table?

Comment: no not yet i have done right join with this . u can help me out with that :)

Comment: Which one is your base table ? Can you edit your question and paste working/existing query (without filtered one)

Comment: SELECT users.*, customers.name FROM users INNER JOIN customers ON customers.id = users.customerId

Comment: @imDevD, have you tried something like this? SELECT users.*, customers.name FROM customers right JOIN users ON customers.id = users.customerId. May I know what other requirements are there in the query that you require?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a **where** condition to minimise the set.

```
$users = User::where('customer_id', '>', 0)->with('customer')->get();
```

Comment: i also need to display all users without customerId too in same response :)